# Google Maps Coordinates in a Circle

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get the whole bunch of co-ordinates after drawing a Circle overlay in Googlemaps ? Basically what i am trying to do is similar to heatmaps but instead i am drawing a circle with the centre as the marker then i wish to find all co-ordinates which fall in that circle.

Comment: There are an infinite number of coordinates inside a circle.  How are the ones you are interested in specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need to find the points on the circle in order to find out whether a point is in the circle or not.

For example, if I understand your purpose correctly, you have a bunch of points like [(lat,lon),...]. You can then try this,

```
Loop points[]
  if distance between (lat,lon) and the marker (center of the markder) < r of the circle
     the poinst is within the circle
```